# Dynamically changing UserControl content at run time with WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

The screen I am trying to create is a multi-part results viewer. When your batch job completes, you will be able to double click on it and open this screen, which will contain a top section of basic data about the batch job that just ran (top 30% of screen, full width), then the lower 70% will consist of a left aligned listbox (20% of the width) with a selection of Sub-Results and a Detail pane taking up the remaining 80% of the width.

The way I want it to behave is when you select the Sub Result on the left listbox, the right hand pane will populate with the details of the sub result. Because it is going to be complex and needs to be scalable, I would like to implement each sub result detail display panel as a UserControl.

The parent ViewModel contains an `IDictionary<Enum.ResultType, IResultPanel>` - and the listbox will be populated from the keys of this dictionary, and when you select an option, it will fetch the IResultPanel object from the dictionary which will be User Control, one example snippet below

```
public partial class SimpleCalcInfoResult : UserControl, IResultPanel
    {
        private SimpleCalcInfoResultViewModel _viewModel;

        public SimpleCalcInfoResult(SimpleCalcInfoResultViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = viewModel;
        }
    }
```

The IResultPanel interface is a blank empty interface, used only to facilitate being able to have the Dictionary above with a common type as I felt having a dictionary of UserControls was too broad.

The problem I've got is I can't figure out what XAML to use in the parent control to have a changeable UserControl panel. Obviously you can have

```
<local:MyControl> ... </local:MyControl>
```

As a hard coded user control, but how can I have a section of XAML that will let me change which User Control is displayed, depending on which ListBox item you select?

Comment: Look into WPF templating, namely DataTemplateSelectors (http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) and DataTemplates (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) with DataType

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is simple to achieve with WPF. However, when using MVVM, we 'manipulate' data rather than UI controls. With that in mind, first declare a `DataTemplate` for each of your custom `Panel` controls in the `Application.Resources` section:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SimpleCalcInfoResultViewModel}">
    <Views:SimpleCalcInfoResult />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now all you have to do is display the relating view model in your lower right display using a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

Finally, add a property of type `IResultPanel` named `ViewModel` to your parent view model:

```
private IResultPanel viewModel = new FirstViewModel();

public IResultPanel ViewModel
{
    get { return viewModel; }
    set { if (viewModel != value) { viewModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewModel"); } }
}
```

Now all you need to do to display a different `Panel` in your application is to set this property to a different value:

```
ViewModel = new SimpleCalcInfoResultViewModel();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, very comprehensive answer. So am I right in thinking I still create and define a UserControl xaml class such as SimpleCalcInfoResult with all the display logic for that result type in, and in the Data Template just specify a single line ie an instance creation of that UserControl?

Comment: One other question, my SimpleCalcInfoResult UserControl has a constructor that takes 1 parameter, a SimpleCalcInfoResultViewModel object. How can I write the datatemplate above to create the user control, passing in the view model object as the first parameter to the constructor?

Comment: Yes to your first comment... that's all you need to do. With these `DataTemplate`s defined, wherever the Framework sees an instance of your view model, it will display the  specified `UserControl`. Your second comment seems to be a bit confused... your constructor takes the view model as a parameter, but with this method, you don't need to do that... the `DataTemplate` takes place of setting the `DataContext`. You can still acess the view model from the `UserControl` code behind by casting its `DataContext` to the correct type of view model: `ThisViewModel vm = (ThisViewModel)DataContext;`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. With part 2 - I have tried what you said but in the constructor for the SimpleCalcInfoResult View, I try to cast the DataContext as you said to the VM type, but the DataContext of the View is null. Have I missed a crucial step?

Comment: It might not have been set by the time the constructor is called. Try using the `Window.Loaded` event and put your code in that handler instead.